# Organizing single page website html code with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, angularjs

I've been looking for a MVC framework for my front end developments. Knockout seemed to deliver everything I was looking for. But now that the page is growing larger with more and more modules or menus, this single file containing all of the HTML content is not really a good approach.

By looking at the angularjs homepage (more specifically the Wire up a Backend example), it seems that this solves the problem thanks to the $routeProvider.

Now knowing that I now have some code done with knockout, I would prefer to integrate this solution in my existing website ratter than rewriting it with angularjs, also I've read that is easier to implement 3rd party UI widgets thanks to custom binding with knockout.

Is there a way of doing this with knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different route.

You can seperate your modules into seperate files, and load them with RequireJS. [The documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html) has an explanation on doing this.

You can start separating your templates into external files, and loading them with [Knockout-External-Templates](https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine).

This should give you sufficient separation and modularity to create an SPA without moving to a different structure/framework, like Angular.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In a more general subject. Do you think it would be a good idea to switch to angularjs anyway? Having google support is something to consider...

Comment: Sorry for double comment. slow mobile net

Comment: That's not something I can really answer. It's going to depend on a lot of personal things. I can tell you that Knockout's support is not trivial though; the project is led by Steve Sanderson, a Microsoft Vet (not sure if he is still with them), and is under very active development. While Angular strives to be a more complete solution (baking in testing, routing, and DI, where Knockout lets you pick your own), I would not say based on the last year that it is getting more "support" than Knockout is. You should really evaluate what it is you need, and try to answer this question yourself.